# Не получается получить данные из формы в контроллер

Tags: java, веб-программирование, spring-mvc

**`index.html`:**

```
    <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
    <%--<%@ taglib prefix='c' uri='http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core' %>--%>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>JavaTrouble</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="main">
      <form action="/findDate" method="post">
        <input type="text" title="введите значение" name="inputDate" class="input-date" value="input Date">
        <button type="submit" class="button-date">submit</button>
      </form>
    
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**`MyController.java`:**

```
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.ui.Model;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    @Controller
    public class MyController {
        @RequestMapping("/findDate")
        public String home(String inputDate, Model model){
            System.out.println(inputDate);
            return "index";
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Для получения данных используйте аннотацию [`@RequestParam`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html):

> Аннотация, указывающия, что параметр метода должен быть привязан к
>   параметру веб-запроса.
>
> Поддерживаются методы аннотированных обработчиков в Spring MVC следующим образом:
>
> - В Spring MVC «параметры запроса» отображают параметры запроса, данные формы и детали запроса из нескольких частей. Это связано с тем,
>     что API-интерфейс Servlet объединяет параметры запроса и формирует
>     данные в единую карту под названием «параметры» и включает
>     автоматический анализ тела запроса.

---

```
public String home(@RequestParam("inputDate") String inputDate, Model model){
```

Comment: даже после такой замены не работает. Возникает ошибка сервера 404
Type Status 
ReportMessage /findDate
Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Comment: @dasha Вы неправы, оно не работает по другой причине.

Comment: [Что означает если ответ "принят"?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)